# Store the counts of children models in parent model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a parent and child class

```
class parent(models.model):
     countChidlren = #count of the total children of this parent

class childeren(models.model):
     parent = models.ForeignKey(parent)
```

I want to have the count of the childeren in parent but don't have any idea on how to go about it.?

Answer (score 0):

Simply way to do it...

```
class Parent(models.model):

    def total_childrens(self):
        return Children.objects.filter(parent__pk=self.pk).count()

class Children(models.model):
     parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
```

for the test,

```
>>> Parent.objects.first().total_childrens()
29
>>>
```

you also can use `@property`

```
class Parent(models.model):

    @property
    def total_childrens(self):
        return Children.objects.filter(parent__pk=self.pk).count()
```

for the test;

```
>>> Parent.objects.first().total_childrens
29
>>>
```